# Keep text inline with indent on lists

Tags: html, css

I have a list which uses :before to add a HEX icon (tick and cross).

However when the text wraps onto the second line, it goes under the icon, i want it to stay inline with the same indent as the text.

I have tried:

```
list-style-position: outside;
```

With no joy, I think this is down to using :before, which I ideally want to keep.

Here is a fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/cfboxrad/363/

Any help would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using a `pseudo` element, so you can position it absolutely on the `li` item. Using a padding on the li:

```css
.review-list {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.review-list--pro,
.review-list--con {
  line-height: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 7px;
  padding-left: 25px;
  position: relative;
}

.review-list--pro:before {
  content: "\2714\0020";
  position: absolute;
  color: #87c44a;
  left: 0px;
}

.review-list--con:before {
  content: "\2717\0020";
  position: absolute;
  color: #f44336;
  left: 0px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="review-list">
  <li class="review-list--pro"><span>this is my textthis is my textthis is my texthis is my textthis is my textthis is my texttthis is my textthis is my textthis is my text</span></li>
  <li class="review-list--pro">this is my text</li>
  <li class="review-list--pro">this is my text</li>
  <li class="review-list--pro">this is my text</li>
</ul>

<ul class="review-list">
  <li class="review-list--con">this is my textthis is my textthis is my textthis is my textthis is my textthis is my textthis is my textthis is my textthis is my text</li>
  <li class="review-list--con">this is my text</li>
  <li class="review-list--con">this is my text</li>
  <li class="review-list--con">this is my text</li>
</ul>
```

Your fiddle updated:
http://jsfiddle.net/cfboxrad/379/

Answer (score 1):

Give the check marks -18 margin on the left, it should come in place of the hidden bullets, also the margin on spans on useless remove it.

```
.review-list {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.review-list--pro, .review-list--con {
  line-height: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 7px;
}

.review-list--pro:before {
  content:"\2714\0020";
  color: #87c44a;
  margin-left: -18px;
}

.review-list--con:before {
  content:"\2717\0020";
  color: #f44336;
  margin-left: -18px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`list-style-position` is a property meant for list elements. It only works well when using the default list bullets or [using graphical bullets via `list-style-image`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/list-style-image).

An easy solution to your problem would to use negative left margin on the pseudo elements:

```css
.review-list {list-style-type: none;}
.review-list span{margin-left:25px;}

.review-list--pro, .review-list--con {
  line-height: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 7px;
}

.review-list--pro:before {
  content:"\2714\0020";
  color: #87c44a;
  margin-left: -1em;
}
.review-list--con:before {
  content:"\2717\0020";
  color: #f44336;
  margin-left: -1.1em;
}
```

```html
<ul class="review-list">
  <li class="review-list--pro"><span>this is my textthis is my textthis is my texthis is my textthis is my textthis is my texttthis is my textthis is my textthis is my text</span></li>
  <li class="review-list--pro">this is my text</li>
  <li class="review-list--pro">this is my text</li>
  <li class="review-list--pro">this is my text</li>
</ul>

<ul class="review-list">
  <li class="review-list--con">this is my textthis is my textthis is my textthis is my textthis is my textthis is my textthis is my textthis is my textthis is my text</li>
  <li class="review-list--con">this is my text</li>
  <li class="review-list--con">this is my text</li>
  <li class="review-list--con">this is my text</li>
</ul>
```